# How to delete a particular row from array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem on deleting a table row data by using JavaScript `splice()` method. But i cant delete the data in the meanwhile delete the first and last row of the array.

$scope.StudentDetails is my array which contains all the data like id,name,dept,age,address.,

```
$scope.deleteData = function (item)
{
    var index = $scope.StudentDetails.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1)
    {
        $scope.StudentDetails.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

[image]
[image]

in the first image i will click delete .then it show below image ..but not delete the exact data.
i am using above coding.

using below code load my data and push to the array and populate the date in the table elements.

```
$scope.Load = function ()
{
    $scope.StudentDetails = [];
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetStudentDetails' }).success(function (data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            $.each(data.Data, function (index, value)
            {
                $scope.StudentDetails.push(value);
            });

            // $scope.checked = false;
        }
    }).error(function ()
    {
        alert("Failed");
    });
}
```

Please help anybody!!!
Thanks In advance!!!

Comment: Can you post more code (including the deletion of first/last entry)?

Comment: what does `item` holds?

Comment: the item ,which holds the row id ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Where does your "exact data" come from? Hardcoded or from an ajax call? In the last casse you should obviously also delete it from your db/json/xml ore other source. In the first case you need to rewrite your code very fast:-)

Comment: this code looks fine, can you post the part where you are binding the click action? maybe it gets called multiple times

Comment: The way your briefed your question is ok, but it doesn't provide sufficient data to get answer.  Better construct a jsfiddle for your problem.  Because you want to delete a row, then where comes the array?

Comment: sir ,when i click the delete button the id is '1' for first row.but it will delete first and last row of the table

Comment: can you create an example in fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to delete the entry in your scope, since it's coming from a ajax source.
It might not be present in your scope anymore, but the next time you open the page `$scope.Load()` will just reload the data source.
You need to write an ajax handler that is capable to delete a student from your, db/json file or wherever_your_data_is stored.
Write your delete function like this:

```
$scope.deleteData = function (item){
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/DeleteStudent'/'+ $routeParams.item }).success(function (data)
    {
       //After succesfull deletion reload the changed scope
        $scope.Load();
    });
};
```

and call it from your html like this:

```
<td><a ng-click="deleteData(your_id_for_this_item)">delete</a> </td>
```

Angular will automaticly update your scope an the dom

Comment: sir this is ok sir ..but if there any way to delete the row without using another call

Comment: No, I don't think so. At some point you have to tell you serversided data that is has changed. You could delay that and add a 'sync now' button that synchronises the datasource with the current scope of your app. But thats not the intention of ajax. In my projects every single keystroke in an Input field causes an update of the data source. There is no submit or save button anymore. Anyhow, for large datafields I do a scope reload only if the field is blurred. But changecalls to the data source happen while typing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest wiring up your delete something like this (this is assuming you are using an ng-repeat for the students):

```
<a data-ng-click="deleteStudent($index)">delete</a>
```

And then in your controller

```
$scope.deleteStudent = funciton(index){
    $scope.studentDetails.splice(index, 1);
};
```

The real problem with your question is that

```
var index = $scope.StudentDetails.indexOf(item);
```

Does not work like you are expecting, it doesn't look through an array of objects for an object.

Comment: This is the solution I also use, but I considered that it indirectly alter the DOM (changing the scope causes ng-repeat to modify the DOM), this is why I put the delete function into a directive, without forgetting to wrap with `$scope.$apply()`. NB: there are some typos mistakes in your answer (that I can't edit because there are less than 6 characters) ;)